# C++: Is it safe to pass an argument like unique_ptr::get() to function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr, temporary

Is is safe to pass a function parameter like `getAName(getA().get())`? `getA()` return a object `unique_ptr<A>`.

I test with the whole code below on VS 2010, it works. But I would like to make sure if it's c++ standard, is it safe with other c++ compilers?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){ cout<<"A()"<<endl;}
    ~A(){ cout<<"~A()"<<endl;}

    string name() { return "A"; }
};

std::unique_ptr<A> getA()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A());;
}

void getAName(A* a)
{
    if(a)
    {
        cout << a->name().c_str() << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    getAName(getA().get());
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs in console are:

```
A()
A
~()
```

Is it necessary to make code as below for safe for all compilers?

```
unique_ptr<A> a = getA();
getAName(a.get());
```

Comment: c_str() not required if you are using cout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is safe. `getA()` returns a [temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) `std::unique_ptr`, which will be destroyed after the full expression, which constains the invocation of `getAName()`. So inside the body of `getAName()` the pointer passed remains valid.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, ...

Note that if the pointer passed in is stored somewhere (e.g. a global variable) and then used later (i.e. after the invocation of `getAName()`), the object pointed by the pointer has been destroyed by the temporary `std::unique_ptr` and the pointer becomes dangled; then deference on it would be [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If this is the case, as you showed, you might need a named variable for it.

Comment: Btw what does UB means ?

Comment: Will it not be Segmentation fault (SIGSEV)

Comment: @Kapil It might be, but doesn't have to be. UB means anything is possible.